# How can i short my if else code which cointais value of variable?

Tags: c

i am trying to short the code but now this is not working. i need to short the code for it's run time.Is there nayone who can told me the error of this code and solution of this code.

```c
# include <stdio.h>
int main( )
{
    int bonus, cy, yoj, yos ;
    printf ( "Enter current year and year of joining " ) ;
    scanf ( "%d %d", &cy, &yoj ) ;
    yos = cy - yoj ;
    ( yos > 3 )? bonus=100:printf ( "Bonus = Rs. %d\n", bonus );
    
    return 0 ;
}
```

From a comment:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main( )
{
    int bonus, cy, yoj, yos;
    printf("Enter current year and year of joining ");
    scanf("%d %d", &cy, &yoj);
    yos = cy - yoj;
    if ( yos > 3 )
    {
        bonus = 2500;
        printf("Bonus = Rs. %d\n", bonus);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is the main code that i want to write in short line.

Comment: Are you also shortening for obfuscating reasons? There is no `if` or `else` that you mention. And that use of ternary operator looks rather abusive. You either evaluate the assignment or the print that uses an uninitialized variable.

Comment: That code does not contain anything that is resulting in significant runtime.  No loops, no recursion... what is it you want to optimize? Maybe optimize for readability first.

Comment: You do not provide enough information to show the error. What input do you provide and output do you expect? What do you get?

Comment: The code has UB (undefined behavior). `bonus` is set _if_ `(yos > 3)` but is _printed_ if _not_, so when the `printf` is called the value of `bonus` is unspecified.

Comment: # include <stdio.h>
int main( )
{
int bonus, cy, yoj, yos ;
printf ( "Enter current year and year of joining " ) ;
scanf ( "%d %d", &cy, &yoj ) ;
yos = cy - yoj ;
if ( yos > 3 )
{
bonus = 2500 ;
printf ( "Bonus = Rs. %d\n", bonus ) ;
}
return 0 ;
}

This is the main code that i want to write in short line.

Comment: There is no else

Comment: Shorting code does not improve run time.

Comment: If the runtime of this code is slow, you have other problems than your C code. This is trivial and should run in near zero time provided the input is readily available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not work like this.

As you do not mention what should happen if `yos < 3` I decided to set bonus to `0`.

```
printf ( "Bonus = Rs. %d\n", bonus = ( yos > 3 ) ? 2500 : 0 );
```